# json to php array cdnjs

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to convert cdnjs api JSON result to php array from this [link](http://api.cdnjs.com/libraries). Here is my code:

```
<pre>
<?php
    $cdnLinks = file_get_contents('http://api.cdnjs.com/libraries');
    $cdnLinks = json_encode($cdnLinks);
    $j = json_decode($cdnLinks);
    print_r($j);
?>
</pre>
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you are doing:

1. Download a string of JSON
2. Encode that string into JSON (you now have a JSON string containing a JSON object)
3. Decode that JSON back to a string of JSON
4. Print the string

You need to skip step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Skip step 2 because the output is already a json string.
To decode a json into an array you also need to use second parameter as true json_decode($jsonObj, true).

Thanks